# jQuery getting attribute of a tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap tabs in my application and on change of a dropdown, i want to find out what tab is currently active and from that, get an attribute from the active tab.

So far I have this: `$("ul#depts li.active").text();` which gets me the text of the active tab.

However, when I try something like `("ul#depts li.active").attr('departmentid')` nothing is returned.

```
<ul id="depts" role="tablist" class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li class=""><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#Disputes" departmentid="2" name="switchDepartment" class="switch">Disputes</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" role="tab" href="#ICA" departmentid="5" name="switchDepartment" class="switch">ICA</a></li>
               </ul>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as per your posted HTML, you have set attribute in anchor tag not in li, so change to:

```
("ul#depts li.active > a").attr('departmentid');
```

Comment: Oh I missed that :/  - That did it! Thanks much

Answer (score 1):

Two basic corrections:

1. Your're missing `$` sign in: `("ul#depts li.active").attr('departmentid')`
2. Deptid is attribute of `<a>` element inside that `li` so it'll be

`$("ul#depts li.active a").attr('departmentid')`

[**`DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/LDkTR/)